# Why can't I write to a canvas after calling clearRect()?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new to JavaScript and thought I would write a quiz for my nephews since they are really into star wars. I've managed to do a 'title screen' and now want to write a pic and three possible answers to the screen. But after clearing the screen on a `mouseup` call I can't seem to write anything to the canvas. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> star wars  </title>
</head>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1400" height="700"  style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
//print intro screen
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pic = new Image();
pic.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(pic, 0,0);

}
pic.src="http://i.imgur.com/wZHhlqt.png";


canvas.onmouseup = function(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1400, 700);
}

ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillText("Question 1 ", 140, 440);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/koj/1/edit

```
canvas.onmouseup = function(){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1400, 700);
   q1();
}

function q1(){
  ctx.font = '40pt Calibri';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillText("Question 1 ", 140, 440);
}
```

that's cause you need to call a function that will do something on click, not at the first runtime. So separate your functions, call them accordingly.
You'll also probably need a counter, to know what's the next question and so on...

Comment: many thanks roko. can you explain by what you mean by 'first runtime?'

Comment: @user2827914 I mean that your click function executes upon 'click' but what you had was both image and text at the same time which means that everything was executed *at the first read-time*. By calling your function with the desired content in the `click event handler` you'll get the desired.